# can't query results of graphql query because am using 2 arrays within each other

Tags: arrays, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Here is my map function, I am using react with gatsby.

when I run my graphiql browser, (an IDE graphql playground) I get group as an array, and edges is also an array.

the query is a static query and the mapping function is inside of a class based react component

```
{group.map(({ edges }) => {
   console.log(group);
     edges.map(index => {
       return <p>Hello</p>
   });
})}
```

However, the p tags are not displaying anything, but if I console.log("hello") it consoles hello 4 times, anyone got any ideas?
I am a little stumped.

the console.log returns

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
edges: Array(2)
0:
node: {tune: "awesome", title: "Awesome Song", playtime: "2:50", page: "249", filesize: "1.8", …}
__proto__: Object
1:
node: {tune: "awesome", title: "AwesomeSong 2", playtime: "4:05", page: "525", filesize: "2.6", …}
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
1:
edges: Array(1)
0:
node: {tune: "decent", title: "Awesome Song3", playtime: "4:06", page: "719", filesize: "2.4", …}
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
2: {edges: Array(1)}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
{group.map(({ edges }) => {
   return edges.map(({node})=> {
       return <p>{node.title}</p>
   });
})}
```

You need to return something in your first `map()` loop.

In addition, are you displaying the loop in a `render()` function? If not, you can't display a `<p>` tag.

Comment: its in a render function

Comment: I am getting really close, so I did what you said, but nothing is displaying... However, I console logged the node, and it returns this ```filename: "422 'Twas on That Night When Doomed to Know.mp3"
filesize: "2.6"
page: "422"
playtime: "4:02"
title: "'Twas on That Night When Doomed to Know"
tune: "good"``` Its strange I can't display it with {node.title}, got any Ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: Has  all your objects exactly the same structure?

Comment: so if I console.log (node.title), it returns the titles completely fine. However, I cannot display anything on my webpage, even <p>Hello World</p> is invisible inside of the map function

Comment: Can you provide the full component/page that has the loop?

Comment: this is my github repo https://github.com/natejsimonsen/dr.new/blob/master/src/pages/accompaniments/sort-by-tune/index.js

Comment: You are missing a return in the first loop. I've updated my answer.