# React mapping function is not returning anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have these mapping functions

```
    let data =
      this.props.data.allSongsJson.group &&
      this.props.data.allSongsJson.group.map(({ edges }) => {
        edges.map(({ node }) => {
          return <p key={node.id}>Hello World</p>;
        });
      });
```

However, the p tags are not returning anything, but I can console log things, so I am really confused, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: share some more code so can understand better what you want to do .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't query results of graphql query because am using 2 arrays within each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268680/cant-query-results-of-graphql-query-because-am-using-2-arrays-within-each-other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have return statement from the first `#Array.map` callback:

```
this.props.data.allSongsJson.group.map(({ edges }) => {
  return edges.map(({ node }) => {
    return <p key={node.id}>Hello World</p>;
  });
});
```